# can we convert a multi-select picklist value into single select picklist value? If so what will be the loss of data

Tags: picklist, configuration, multi-select

Requirement:- we need to convert a multi-select picklist value into single select picklist value.if We change the Multiselect to Single .how we can avoid data loss

Comment: If there is record that currently have 3 picklist values, how do you want to convert it into single value?

Comment: Yes that is the business requirement.I already Explained its not possible ,but posted for any solution/workaround.

Comment: You can suggest that in case record have more than 1 picklist value, then you will put there only first value (after changing it single picklist). If it's fine, use the solution Sharvan suggest below. If it's not, require conversion logic from the person who raise the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will be losing data if Changing from multi Picklist to any other type. It's not possible to avoid while conversion but we can do with apex data loader with minimal risk.

1. Take a backup
2. convert to picklist
3. Remove multi select to single value in csv file with respect to your requirement
4. upload into salesforce.

[documentation Link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_on_changing_custom_field_types.htm&type=0)

Comment: Now the Requirment is The Value listed First in Mulitselect for perticular record needs to be set in single  Picklist after Changing to Single Picklist. Is there any option to set fist value in record when we convert multi select to single picklist.Please suggest

Comment: you have to play with csv file. it's not possible in salesforce