# Need to convert Multi-select picklist to Single Picklist

Tags: custom-field, validation-rule, object

The **multiselect Picklist API Name** is used in Validation Rule and `Apex test Class`.

Is it require to remove references before changing the field type to Single Picklist.Please Suggest

Comment: As i checked and noticed that we cannot change field type without removing references.but i have almost 70 references in classes,trigger,validation.How can i achieve this.

Comment: Is it different from previous question: 
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/147030/can-we-convert-a-multi-select-picklist-value-into-single-select-picklist-value

Comment: Yes PraveenKumar.The previous Question was related to data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to remove reference from Apex code. so Now you have two Options here.

1. Remove the reference and change the type and then again add it back.
2. Create a new picklist field(if this is not managed package) then take backup in Eclipse and then in Eclipse using replace the old API name with new API name. Then delete the old API name. Benefit of this approach you can easily change this using eclipse. Also when you delete the old field so if you forgot to update somewhere in code you will get notification for that so you can fix that as well (unless you are not using in dynamic `soql` then you have to depend upon Eclipse search.)

So I suggest you to go with step 2.

**PS:** Instead of doing all these changes in Production I suggest you to first do this in SB and once you check everything then deploy in production. So you need to deploy only one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to remove reference while changing multi picklist to picklist. I tried just now. It throws following error.

**Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)**
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Cannot change field type of a custom field referenced in Apex class or trigger: [Multiselect](/01p2800000DYHog)".

Comment: Thanks shravan.But my question is then how to do it in Production..In production first 1)we need to comment the code and deploy in PROD. 2)Change the Field type 3) then uncomment the code and again need to deploy in PROD. Is there any other way to do this in simple way

Comment: Yes Dem. but you can try this. 1. comment reference 2. change type 3. then deployee  4. uncomment and deploy again. Deployment component will have some order